# Is there a way to use a prompt box as a password?

Tags: javascript

Can we mask the text on a prompt box? If there is a way can someone please guide me. According to most of my research on internet this feature is not supported in Javascript. Is this true?

Comment: As you saw, there's no way to hide the content of a prompt. I would suggest using an HTML form with an `<input type="password"`, possibly in a pop-in modal to simulate the "dialog box" of prompt.

Comment: this is the worst way to request a password, you can mask an input element using `<input name="myPassword" type="password" />`

Comment: You can't because `prompt` is not designed to HIDE what's being typed in. If you require hidden text, use an alternative, such as [SweetAlert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) or any other type of modal.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a `<input type="password">`. [see MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password)

If you really need a prompt popup, you can try [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#prompt-with-password). as you can see in the examples page, there is a password type predefined.